# Laravel Passport Always unathenticated

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-passport

I've set up a new Laravel project and I'm planning to use Laravel Passport to manage the authentication of my api.

I've got login and registration working, but showing details doesnt.

I'm testing using postman making a post request to `/api/details` with the following data:

```
Authorization:Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjgwYmNhOGEzMTBmZjc2YTg0NTdkMTRjOTk0Y2VkNzMzODUwNDZkYjRhMzBhYjRjOTM0MWFlMGI4Y2I4MzRjMGU3MjY2ZjY5NjMwYTlmZjNmIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiODBiY2E4YTMxMGZmNzZhODQ1N2QxNGM5OTRjZWQ3MzM4NTA0NmRiNGEzMGFiNGM5MzQxYWUwYjhjYjgzNGMwZTcyNjZmNjk2MzBhOWZmM2YiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTMxMTY4NjEsIm5iZiI6MTU1MzExNjg2MSwiZXhwIjoxNTg0NzM5MjYxLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.I66xwDmnc5O7NmaiXDYLiZATDGOBnicDgA94VhX8OKJ8wcRnZ9g0vgMIZRPWEmIXqxfdffQ8FR3LA3iB-nzVZhzFoPg8Bu17T739dU7fqjiM7t9dWSo1X_xUL-sumunppTQz-mAubQTS3wEXzfX1o72Z2eOd4pK9XxQCetDaGGkMwFqEmwr7FFddR9oITO3_KABGDiyE8LZDqzVMBDKEamOFdtLuMhIdJKuBFxetPJYF9WWQNXEvOOhS_o_XYISummFle52qnmpkDEVrR8QxYiy6CaNZN7KFHs2eTdb84ovNWGldzbBat6W8wBa4SuMz6rRgYmNjlbZpCHLNtxMOe7O1hziBZOHgpiw_bdRs4gD03AEsQk-_ADCfKTwaS6g3jcXNkkOcNITxaLdJEfVPH_d6iGftJXZtF_wv_JIpWEtxF--dN28wtI1Jvjf7DbdkOYpDYii-aXJDYLZFtMAb5_nzGS1ohjvoG3bNhn5jz2ugJ5IoB7cOwb22Kkc7jz37SCkAPzKvgUwNACIJ3lVfvToW7WlQDLo2nwubV9KMYVPoKc30CGMM5sdaqvQCPSQQTB3OQbG9bSIfA1uuPAaK7WKjPLOU1G3DavUc6kr0WhxcQS2wteuheKz3T_i9frrgUoknqHC5Tr-Y-DioXZP56CUOSXyqd9ABYEMzHLqyBt8

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-rurlencoded

Accept: application/json
```

I run the login first and get returned the above token, but I always get the `{"message":"Unauthenticated."}` response.

Here's my code:

Api.php

```
<?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/
Route::post('login', 'API\UserController@login');
Route::post('register', 'API\UserController@register');
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::post('details', 'API\UserController@details');
});
```

AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate; 
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{ 
    /** 
     * The policy mappings for the application. 
     * 
     * @var array 
     */ 
    protected $policies = [ 
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy', 
    ];
/** 
     * Register any authentication / authorization services. 
     * 
     * @return void 
     */ 
    public function boot() 
    { 
        $this->registerPolicies(); 
        Passport::routes(); 

        Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addYears(20));

        Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addYears(20));
    } 
}
```

Auth.php

```
<?php
return [
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the options for resetting passwords including the view
    | that is your password reset e-mail. You may also set the name of the
    | table that maintains all of the reset tokens for your application.
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
];
```

UsersController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; 
use App\User; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; 
use Validator;
class UserController extends Controller 
{
public $successStatus = 200;
/** 
     * login api 
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
     */ 
    public function login(){ 
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){ 
            $user = Auth::user(); 
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus); 
        } 
        else{ 
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
        } 
    }
/** 
     * Register api 
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
     */ 
    public function register(Request $request) 
    { 
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
            'name' => 'required', 
            'email' => 'required|email', 
            'password' => 'required', 
            'c_password' => 'required|same:password', 
        ]);
if ($validator->fails()) { 
            return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);            
        }
$input = $request->all(); 
        $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']); 
        $user = User::create($input); 
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
        $success['name'] =  $user->name;
return response()->json(['success'=>$success], $this-> successStatus); 
    }
/** 
     * details api 
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
     */ 
    public function details() 
    { 
        $user = Auth::user(); 
        return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this-> successStatus); 
    } 
}
```

User.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
  use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
/**
* The attributes that are mass assignable.
*
* @var array
*/
protected $fillable = [
'name', 'email', 'password',
];
/**
* The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
*
* @var array
*/
protected $hidden = [
'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

Can someone point out how to get this working please?

**Laravel verion: 5.8.5**

Answer (score 0):

In your `AuthServiceProvider.php` you need to include Passport with

```
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
```

and at the end of the boot() method, you should add

```
Passport::routes();
```

In your User.php have you also added the `HasApiTokens` Trait?

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable, SoftDeletes;
```

Comment: I've updared my question to include User.php. It did have `HasApiTokens`. I also tried moving `Passport::routes();` to the end of the boot method but still the same `{"message":"Unauthenticated."}` result

Comment: Have you also run `php artisan passport:install` ?

Comment: ok so it seems everything is set up correctly, nothing is screaming out that there is a problem with the setup (because you can login). Which leads me to believe that the bearer token itself is bad... where did you get it from ?

Comment: So i send a request to `/api/login` with a username and password. I get the token form the response: ```{"success":{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjVkZjc0MDcwYzRiZmU4ODA4ZjVjYWZkMjU0NmNmZWExZDQ4NDAzMDBmMmFjZjU2MGFiMWFjMGNiNzFiY2ViZDM4YjM1ODVkYzQ3YzU4ZWFmIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIzIiwianRpIjoiNWRmNzQwNzBjNGJmZTg4MDhmNWNhZmQyNTQ2Y2ZlYTFkNDg0MDMwMGYyYWNmNTYwYWIxYWMwY2I3MWJjZWJkMzhiMzU4NWRjNDdjNThlYWYiLCJpYX...}} ```

Comment: It's a tricky one without having it infront of me.. the only thing I can think is that the details() method doesn't have the Request passed in but that shouldn't matter

Comment: @TEster have you solved the issue? I'm running to same Exception on login

Comment: @TEster you have done that? Please provide us that solution. Thanks.

Comment: @WebDeveloper did you find any answer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the nature of your application, if its only going to be used for an API take a look at `config/auth.php` and change the `defaults.guard` to be api

```
 'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',           
    'passwords' => 'users',
],
```

Comment: That causes this ```"message": "Method Illuminate\\Auth\\RequestGuard::attempt does not exist.",
    "exception": "BadMethodCallException",
    "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php",
    "line": 102,```

Comment: strange, because you do have that guard in your auth.php, revert that change and try to do a `composer dump-autoload` if that doesn't work I'm at a loss I'm afraid